# $C_{\operatorname{Aut}(Q)}(\operatorname{Inn}(Q)) = \operatorname{Inn}(Q)$?

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

Let $Q$ be the quaternion group of order $8$. Write $G = \operatorname{Aut}(Q)$ and $N = \operatorname{Inn}(Q)$. Show that $C_G(N) = N$

---

*What I tried*

I know that $C_G(N) = \{g \in G : gN = Ng\}$. I already know that $nN =Nn$ if $n \in N$, which means that $C_G(N) \supseteq N$.

For $C_G(N) \subseteq N$, all I need to show is that 
$$
\forall g \in G \setminus N, \exists n \in N, \quad gng^{-1} \notin N
$$
In other words, I have to show that if $\phi : Q \rightarrow Q$ is an arbitrary isomorfism, that cannot be written as a conjugation, there is some $y \in Q$ such that
$$
\text{for each }q \in Q, \qquad 
\left(x \ \mapsto \ \phi(y\phi^{-1}(x)y^{-1})\right)
\quad \neq \quad 
\left( x \ \mapsto \ qzq^{-1}\right) 
$$
I rewrote $\phi(y\phi^{-1}(x)y^{-1}) = \phi(y)x\phi(y)^{-1}$

But this is a conjugation right? Did I mess things up somewhere?

Comment: To show that $C_G(N) \supseteq N$, you have to show that $nm=mn$ for all $n,m \in N$, not just that $nN=Nn$. Also, to show that $C_G(N) \subseteq N$, you have to show that $gng^{-1} \ne n$, not that $gng^{-1} \not\in N$. (In fact, as you have shown, it is true that $gng^{-1} \in N$.) To do this, you will need to work out what $G$ is.

Comment: Other approach - more directly, see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195932/automorphism-group-of-the-quaternion-group, $Aut(Q) \cong S_4$ and $Inn(Q) \cong V_4$.

Comment: This one is also relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30108/centralizer-of-inng-in-autg/30379#30379

Comment: What is $C_G(N)$? Is that the commutator subgroup?