# Proof of theorem: If $G$ is a finite nonabelian $p$-group, then $\mathrm{Aut}_c(G)=\mathrm{Inn}(G)$ if and only if $G′=Z(G)$ and $Z(G)$ is cyclic.

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, p-groups

Consider the following theorem:

If $G$ is a finite nonabelian $p$-group, 
   then $\operatorname{Aut}_c(G)=\operatorname{Inn}(G)$ if and only if $G′=Z(G)$ and $Z(G)$ is cyclic.

Notation

- $p$ is a prime number
- $G'$ is the commutator subgroup of $G$
- $Z(G)$ is the center of $G$
- $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ is the automorphism group of $G$
- $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$ is the group of inner automorphisms of $G$
- $\operatorname{Aut}_c(G)$ is the group of central automorphisms of $G$. These are automorphisms which commute with every element of $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$.

I am looking for a proof which is available online free of charge. There is a reference in [Centralizer of $Inn(G)$ in $Aut(G)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30108/centralizer-of-inng-in-autg/30379#30379) but it is not free of charge.

This is **not** any form of homework or other assignment.

Thank you very much for any help, ideas or references!!

Comment: Is this for general interest, or an assignment? Have you tried it yourself? It's also good practise to put the main question (in this case, the theorem in your title) in the body of your question as well.

Comment: @Bill Wallis: This is for my personal interest. I have no assignments. Thanky you for the advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paper you are looking for is [this](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1081/AGB-100002170?journalCode=lagb20): "Central automorphisms that are almost inner", by Curran and McCaughan. Can you provide an e-mail address? I'll be happy to send you a copy.

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for! A copy would be really great. If you are so kind, please send it to my.library@ist-einmalig.de

Comment: Thank you again! The internet is really great.

Comment: @the_fox: What a nice offer! +1

Comment: Happy to help :)