# For which categories we can solve $\text{Aut}(X) \cong G$ for every group $G$?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, big-list

It is usually said that groups can (or should) be thought of as "symmetries of things". The reason is that the "things" which we study in mathematics usually form a category and for every object $X$ of a (locally small) category $\mathcal{C}$, the set of automorphisms (symmetries) of $X$, denoted by $\text{Aut}_{\mathcal{C}}(X)$, forms a group.

My question is: Which categories that occur naturally in mathematics admit all kinds of symmetries? More precisely, for which categories we can solve the equation (of course up to isomorphism) $$\text{Aut}_{\mathcal{C}}(X) = G$$ for every group $G$?

I will write what I could find myself about this, which also hopefully illustrates what kind of answers that would interest me:

Negative for $\mathsf{Set}$: Infinite sets have infinite symmetry groups and for finite sets we get $S_n$'s. So if we let $G$ to be any finite group which is not isomorphic to some $S_n$, the equation has no solution.

Negative for $\mathsf{Grp}$: 
[No group can have its automorphism group a cyclic group of odd order.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40098/cyclic-automorphism-group)

Positive for $\mathsf{Grph}$ (category of graphs): 
[Frucht's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frucht's_theorem) settles this for finite groups. Also according to the wikipedia page, the general situation was solved independently by de Groot and Sabidussi.

An obvious necessary condition is that $\mathcal{C}$ should be a large category.

[This paper](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/documenta/vol-06/16.pdf) shows that the equation can be solved if $\mathcal{C}$ is the category of Riemann surfaces with holomorphic mappings and $G$ is countable.

If we take $\mathcal{C}$ to be the category of fields with zero characteristic, I guess the equation relates to the inverse Galois problem. Edit: This may be much easier than the inverse Galois problem, as Martin Brandenburg commented.

Comment: Notice that it works too for edge-labeled directed graphs thanks to Cayley graphs.

Comment: Community wiki?

Comment: Finite posets yield all finite groups, but I'm not sure about infinite groups via infinite posets.

Comment: In **Set** the singleton object **1** is its own group, since $\hom(\mathbf{1},\mathbf{1})\cong\mathbf{1}$...although you may reject this because it's a (canonical) isomorphism, and not an equality...

Comment: @AlexNelson I think you misread the question.

Comment: Nice question! But if you want to have any connection with the inverse Galois theory, you should restrict yourself to *finite* groups and the category of finite Galois extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$. I suspect that the problem for the category of all extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ is much simpler (perhaps already solved).

Comment: I wonder what happens when $C$ is the category of affine varieties (over a fixed field $k$).

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1713455/examples-of-classes-mathcalc-of-structures-such-that-every-finite-group-

Answer (score 8):

Every finite group arises as the automorphism group of a finite poset. This is the subject of *Automorphism groups of finite posets* by J. A. Barmak and E. G. Minian, available [online](http://mate.dm.uba.ar/~jbarmak/automorphismgroups.pdf).

Since the category of finite posets is isomorphic(!) to the category of finite $T_0$ spaces, in particular every finite group is the automorphism group of a topological space. More generally, it is proven in *Spaces with given homeomorphism groups* by Thornton, also available [online](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-033-01/S0002-9939-1972-0292054-3/S0002-9939-1972-0292054-3.pdf), that every finitely generated group is the automorphism group of a topological space. I wonder if we can realize every group?

The paper *Representing a Profinite Group as the Homeomorphism Group of a Continuum*
by K. H. Hofmann and S. A. Morris, available [online](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.3876.pdf), deals with the question whether every profinite group is isomorphic to the automorphism group of a compact connected space (endowed with the compact open topology).