# How general are $\mathrm{Aut}$ groups and $\mathrm{End}$ rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, category-theory

For any locally small category $X$ and object $A\in X$ the set $\mathrm{Aut}_X(A)$ is a group w.r.t. composition $\circ$.
For any locally small abelian category $X$ and object $A\in X$ the set $\mathrm{End}_X(A)$ is a ring w.r.t. $+,\circ$.

1. Does for any group $G$ exist $X$ and $A$ with $G\cong\mathrm{Aut}_X(A)$? We know that $G$ is a quotient of the free group $F_G$, and is a subgroup of the permutation group $S_G=\mathrm{Aut}_{Set}(G)$.
2. Does for any unital ring $R$ exist $X$ and $A$ with $G\cong\mathrm{End}_X(A)$? We know that $R$ is a quotient of the free ring $\mathbb{Z}\langle R|\emptyset\rangle$. Is it also a subring of some 'typical' ring? Perhaps $\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(?)$.

This [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165712/for-which-categories-we-can-solve-textautx-cong-g-for-every-group-g?rq=1) is related.

Comment: Are you familiar with the way in which a group can be viewed as a one-object category itself? Presumably that would be a rather trivial way of answering your question?

Comment: Hmm, you're right. Though I had in mind more 'algebraic' categories (of all Groups, Rings, Modules, Algebras, Lattices, Universal algebras, and varieties within).

Comment: I think that it's a two stars general. Maybe three stars, I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying, Asaf.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_general_%28United_States%29 :-) It's a joke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Edit: my initial remarks were based on an answer I discarded: sorry for the confusion]

1. Let $G$ be an arbitrary group, and let $\mathsf{Set}(G)$ be the category of sets with (right) $G$-action. The group $G$ acts on itself by multiplication on the right, and it is easy to check that $\operatorname{End}_{\mathsf{Set}(G)}(G)=\operatorname{Aut}_{\mathsf{Set}(G)}(G)=G$, with $g\in G$ corresponding to $\lambda_g:G\to G$ given by $\lambda_g(h) = g h$.
2. This is essentially identical. Let $\mathsf{Mod}(R)$ be the category of right $R$-modules. It is easy to check that $\operatorname{End}_{\mathsf{Mod}(R)}(R)=R$, where $r\in R$ corresponds to $\lambda_r:R\to R$ given by $\lambda_r(s)=r s$.

**Edit:** The groups $\operatorname{Aut}_{\mathsf{Set}}(A)$ are all permutation groups (finite or infinite). On the other hand, I do not think groups of the form $\operatorname{Aut}_{\mathsf{Grp}}(A)$ or $\operatorname{Aut}_{\mathsf{Mod}(R)}(M)$ have been classified, except perhaps for very special cases of $R$ (e.g. if $R$ is a field then $\operatorname{Aut}_R(M)$ will be a general linear group over $R$).

Comment: May I have a follow-up question? How general are groups $\mathrm{Aut}_{X}(A)$ for $X=Set, Grp, Ring, R\text{-}Mod, R\text{-}Alg$?

Comment: @Leon not every group is the automorphism group of a group, if that is what you mean. The canonical example is $\mathbb{Z}$. I posted a proof of this on MSE a while ago, and i'll maybe try and find it tomorrow...I should say, however, that every group is the *outer* automorphism group of some group.

Comment: The post I mentioned above is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253936/is-every-group-the-automorphism-group-of-a-group/256173