# If $p$ is an odd prime then prove that there cannot exist a finite group $G$ such that ${\rm Aut}(G)\cong \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism, automorphism-group

> If $p$ is an odd prime then prove that there cannot exist a finite group $G$ such that ${\rm Aut}(G)\cong \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Can anyone tell me how to proceed in this question?

Here is my attempt:

If ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is cyclic then ${\rm Inn}(G)$ is also cyclic which implies $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic which implies $G$ is abelian.
If $G$ is abelian then for $\phi \in{\rm Aut}(G)$ such that $\phi(g)=g^{-1}$. then $\phi(\phi(g)) = \phi(g^{-1}) = g$. Hence $\phi$ is of order $2.$

Hence the order of ${\rm Aut}(G)$ must be a multiple of 2 and hence cannot have prime order.

Edit:- I cannot seem to proceed when $\phi$ becomes just the identity mapping. In that case every element of the group has order $2$ (except for the identity element of order $1$) .

Comment: One way to proceed is to search the site to see if the question has been asked before. Try [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40098/) for example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cyclic Automorphism group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40098/cyclic-automorphism-group)

Comment: @ArsenBerk I have edited the question to include my effort...can you please look into it?

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes thank you very much.....This was the final detail I was missing. Thanks for quick reply. I think it is because then $\phi$ fails to be a homomorphism...am I correct?

Comment: You are not quite there: $\phi$ could be trivial and then you are dealing with an elementary abelian $2$-group.

Comment: But you still need to consider the case when $\phi$ has order $1$, so your proof is not yet complete.

Comment: @DerekHolt How do I proceed when $\phi$ is the identity? . Is there some other theorem I need to know about automorphisms of abelian 2-groups?

Comment: Please try and put some effort into solving this problem yourself. What happens when $|G|=4$ for example?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: yes $G$ is abelian and consider the map $\phi$: $G \rightarrow G$, defined by $\phi(g)=g^{-1}$. Prove that this is an isomorphism. What is the order of $\phi$?

Comment: This is the correct argument but you have to say something more to cover the case when $g\mapsto g^{-1}$ is actually the identity.

Comment: Yes I know, I leave that of course to @Arghyadeep etc. Remember, this is a *Hint*.

Comment: @NickyHekster How do I proceed when $\phi$ is the identity mapping ? In that case all elemets of the group is of order $2$ except the identity element.

Comment: @Arghyadeep Chatterjee: note that in this case $G=\mathbb{F}_2^r$ for some $r \geq 1$ and you can compute the automorphism group (eg show it’s not abelian).

Comment: @Mindlack I do not understand what F^r2 means. I am a noob in group theory.

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17054/group-where-every-element-is-order-2

Comment: @Arghyadeep Chatterjee: $\mathbb{F}_2$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Let $e_i$ be the vector with zeroes everywhere except a $1$ at the $i$-th place. Show that the group has an automorphism of order $2$, which exchanges $e_1$ and $e_2$.