# On automorphisms of infinite abelian 2-groups

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ to be a infinite abelian 2-group. 
I want to know information in structure of group automorphism of $G$.
For example $\alpha$ such that $\alpha(x)=x^{-1}$ for all $x\in G$ is an automorphism of $G$.
Do we can find other automorphisms of $G$?

Comment: In general? Depends on your set theory. There are set theories in which there exist infinite abelian groups of exponent $2$ with no non-trivial automorphisms (see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28145/axiom-of-choice-and-automorphisms-of-vector-spaces)). The automorphism you give would be the identity in that case.