# Is every group the automorphism group of a group?

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, abstract-algebra

Suppose $G$ is a group. Does there always exist a group $H$, such that $\operatorname{Aut}(H)=G$, i. e. such that $G$ is the automorphism group of $H$?

**EDIT:** It has been pointed out that  the answer to the above question is *no*. But I would be much more pleased if someone could give an example of such a group $G$ not arising as an automorphism group together with a comparatively easy proof of this fact.

Comment: @rondo9 Why does $\mbox{Aut}G$ simple imply that $G$ is abelian?  What if $G$ has a trivial outer automorphism group?

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake.

Comment: This overflow link does not directly address what you are asking, but may be of some interes: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/37356/realizing-groups-as-automorphism-groups-of-graphs

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345052

Comment: By the way, "any finite group occurs as a certain quotient of Aut(G) for some finite p-group G" - https://arxiv.org/pdf/0711.2816.pdf

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Theorem.** The following cyclic groups cannot be the automorphism group of any group:

1. The infinite cyclic group $C_{\infty}$ (also known as $\mathbb{Z}$), and
2. Cyclic groups $C_{n}$ of odd order (also known as $\mathbb{Z}_n$ or $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$).

The proof is relatively straight forward, with a subtlety at the end, and consists of two lemmata. I shall leave you to pin the lemmata together and get the result. (**Hint.** what are the inner automorphisms isomorphic to?)

**Lemma 1:** If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian.

Proof: This is a standard undergrad question, so I'll let you figure out the proof for yourself.

**Lemma 2:** If $G\not\cong C_2$ is abelian then $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ has an element of order two.

(Here, $C_2$ is the cyclic group of order two. Note that this group has trivial automorphism group.)

Proof: The negation map $n: a\mapsto a^{-1}$ is non-trivial of order two unless $G$ comprises of elements of order two. If $G$ consists only of elements of order two then, applying the Axiom of Choice, $G$ is the direct sum of cyclic groups of order two, $$G\cong C_2\times C_2\times\ldots$$ See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/444172/10513) for why. Finally, because $G\not\cong C_2$ there are at least two copies of $C_2$, and so we can switch them (and "switching" has order two).

---

The subtlety I mentioned at the start is the use of Choice in the proof of Lemma 2. If we do not assume Choice that it is consistent that there exists a group $G$ of order greater than two such that $\operatorname{Aut(G)}$ is trivial. This was (first) proven by Asaf Karagila in an answer to [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/28145/10513).

Answer (score 8):

[Evidently](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02884017) this is false even if $H$ is required to be finite.

I think the argument would be very difficult if $G$ was allowed to be infinite, especially if $G$ was not finitely generated.

EDIT: [Here](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract;jsessionid=4BCFCD84526CB52707E5E795CFFD9270.journals?fromPage=online&aid=94925) is a cool somewhat related result.

Comment: Thanks for the references but, unfortunately, they are behind a paywall. Do you know any articles which one can find on a free platform (i. e. on arxiv)?

Comment: @Dominik Sorry, no I don't. I was able to find them at my university library. If you're a student, they will likely be accessible from yours, too.

Comment: @Dominik: Check out the third paper on Inna Bumagin's webpage, [here](http://people.math.carleton.ca/~bumagin/papers/papers.htm). She and Dani Wise proved that every countable group $Q$ is the outer automorphism group of a finitely generated group $N$. Their proof is, if I remember correctly, pretty self-contained. Their results about $N$ being residually finite when $Q$ is finitely presented can be ignored, as this is immediate from Wise's latest work (he has proven, among other amazing things, that every $C^{\prime}(1/6)$-group is residually finite, which solves the problem here.)