# Automorphism group of Baumslag - Solitar group BS(1,2)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $BS(1,2)= \langle a,b \mid bab^{-1} = a^2 \rangle$.

I would like to know if $Aut(BS(1,2))$ is finitely generated or not. And if yes, what are those generators.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/825580/the-automorphism-group-of-a-finitely-generated-group : this may be of interest.

Comment: So it is the case that BS(1,2) is not finitely generated but is there an infinite set of generators for $Aut(BS(1,2))$?

Answer (score 1):

This automorphism group is finitely generated, according to the reference given in [the automorphism group of a finitely generated group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/825580/the-automorphism-group-of-a-finitely-generated-group#comment1708618_825592)

Comment: See the middle of the 2nd page of the pdf "Tree actions of automorphism groups" given in my link. It is said : "Also of interest in this context is a further result of Collins[3] giving a finite presentation for Aut(G) in the case where p=1 and |q|>1".

Comment: $\mathrm{Aut}(BS(p,q))$ is not finitely generated if and only if $|p|\neq 1$ and $|q|\neq 1$.

Comment: You are right. I saw that paper by collins, and that answers the question. Thanks.