# Groups which can not occur as automorphism group of a group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-group

Consider the following natural question:

> Given a finite group $H$, does there exists a finite group $G$ such that $\mathrm{Aut}(G)\cong H$?

In short, does any finite group occurs as the automorphism group (of some group)? The answer is NO. For example, $H=\mathbb{Z}_3$. Another counter-example is $H=Q_8$, the quaternion group of order $8$ (I leave their verification to interested reader). Note that $\mathbb{Z}_4$ occurs as automorphism group of $\mathbb{Z}_5$. This raises following two questions to me:

> 1. Among finite abelian groups, which groups can occur as automorphism groups?
> 2. Is there any other non-abelian finite group which can not occur as automorphism group?

Perhaps first question is easy to answer since structure of automorphism group of finite abelian groups is well known; I don't know its complete answer. For second question, I would be happy to see if there is an infinite family of counterexamples.

Comment: For 2, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253936/is-every-group-the-automorphism-group-of-a-group.

Answer (score 12):

There are several results addressing this question. MacHale proved $1983$ in his article [Some Finite Groups Which Are Rarely Automorphism Groups](http://www.jstor.org/stable/20489177?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

Theorem: There is no group $G$ such that $Aut(G)$ is abelian of order $p^5$,
$p^6$ or $p^7$ for a prime $p$.

Theorem: There is no group $G$ such that $Aut(G)$ has order $p^4$, for odd prime $p$.

More recently, Ban an Yu showed:

Theorem: there is no group $G$ such that $Aut(G)$ is an abelian $p$-group of order $n<p^{12}$, where $p>2$ is a prime, but there is one with $|Aut(G)|=p^{12}$.

For the abelian case: There is no group $G$ such that $Aut(G)\cong C_n$ for $n>1$ odd, see [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0ahUKEwjuv6bhjpjMAhVsCpoKHR35D84QFghCMAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.emis.de%2Fjournals%2FMPRIA%2F2004%2Fpa104i2%2Fpdf%2F104a211.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEozjTtDGr5d-UFMqtsPVvcGZclxA&sig2=1EVWTpb7BdY6i5GQejy5oQ&bvm=bv.119745492,d.bGs). A full classification of abelian groups occuring as automorphism groups of finite groups is still not known.