# Without choice, what can be the (finite) automorphism groups of $\mathbb F_2$-vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, set-theory, axiom-of-choice, automorphism-group

My motivation for this question is similar to the one in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/28145/1303369). However, that question only asks about the possibility of an infinite $\mathbb F_2$-vector space having trivial automorphism group. What other finite automorphism groups can occur? In particular, can $\mathbb Z/(3)$ occur? (see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1747784/1303369) for extra motivation).

Comment: Oh, man, that answer I wrote to that question was the basis for my masters thesis.

Answer (score 5):

The question about $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ is answered (positively) by Andreas Blass in [this MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/45228).