# Automorphism Group of Simple Graph

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, graph-theory, automorphism-group

Suppose $G$ is a group. Does there always exist a simple graph $\Gamma$ such that $Aut(\Gamma)=G$,  i. e. such that $G$ is the automorphism group of $\Gamma$?

Given [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253936/is-every-group-the-automorphism-group-of-a-group) I'd say no, but I would really appreciate if someone could help figure out an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some Googling and found [Frucht's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frucht%27s_theorem). The argument seems to involve modifying the Cayley graph of $G$ to remove colors and orientations while not introducing extra automorphisms.