# If ${\rm Aut}(G) = 1$ , show that order of $G$ is $1$ or $2.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, automorphism-group

Let $G$ be a group such that ${\rm Aut}(G) = 1.$ I know that $G$ is abelian and that every element of $G$ satisfies the equation $x^2 = 1.$ This can be shown by considering the mapping $x \mapsto x^{-1}$ which is an automorphism.

I want to show that the order of $G$ is $1$ or $2.$ Is it sufficient to note that since $G$ is abelian and every element of $G$ satisfies $x^2 = 1$, then $G$ has non-identity automorphism if the group contains more than two elements? I was wondering if this would suffice or do we need to prove this more rigorously?

Comment: How do you know that $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ has a non-identity element if $G$ contains more than two elements? This is the crux of the claim, so yeah, you should explain why that's true. Like, what would the non-identity automorphism be?

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395569/let-g-be-a-finite-group-with-g2-prove-that-autg-contains-at-least-tw?rq=1