# When the automorphism group is trivial......

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ is a trivial group , obviously $Aut(G)$  is  trivial . Does the converse  hold $?$ .

When  we  are  given  that a  group $G$  has  trivial  automorphism  group , can we  conclude  that the group  will  be  trivial $?$ .

I  guess  not . For  one  thing , we know  that  $$G/Z(G)\cong Inn(G)$$. So , $Aut(G)$ being  trivial  would  imply  that $$G\cong Z(G)$$  i.e.  $G$  is  commutative . But I  see  nothing about $G'$s being trivial .

The problem  is  that  while I cannot  prove  it , I  could  not  find  a  counter example  either , from  among  the  groups  I  am  familiar  with .

What  is  the non-trivial  commutative  group  that  has  trivial  automorphism  group  $?$

Comment: [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8379/g2-implies-g-has-non-trivial-automorphism?rq=1) provides an answer: $\mathrm{Aut}(G)=1$ iff $G=1$ or $G\cong\mathbf C_2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $G$ is abelian, $x \mapsto x^{-1}$ is an automorphism. If it is trivial, all elements have order at most $2$, hence $G$ is a $\mathbb F_2$-vectorspace. A vectorspace has non-trivial automorphism if the dimension is at least $2$ (any permutation of the basis will do). Hence the dimension must be $\leq 1$ and we end up with $G=\mathbb F_2$ or $G$ trivial.