# Understanding the non-trivial automorphism which exists on $G$

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

> Assume that $G$ is a finite group such that $|G| \gt 1$ and there
>   exists $x \in G$ such that $x^2 \neq e$.   Prove that there exists a
>   non-trivial automorphism on $G$.

Note: This question has been asked and answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8379/g2-implies-g-has-non-trivial-automorphism). But, I can't understand that answers. Both of them use the concept of inner-automorphism. We haven't studied this in the class, So i'm not allowed to use the term 'Inner-Automorphism'. Also, I don't understand that what is their automorphism doing. We are given a group. Maybe its abelian. Maybe it's not. We should provide a function which takes an element of $G$ and maps it to another element of $G$. Which element is that another element?

Comment: You will need to know what an [inner automorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_automorphism) is of $G$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $G$ is abelian, then $\phi:g \mapsto g^{-1}$ is a non-trivial automorphism because $\phi(x)\ne x$.

If $G$ is not abelian, there are elements $a,b \in G$ such that $ab\ne ba$. Then $\phi:g \mapsto a^{-1}ga$ is a non-trivial automorphism because $\phi(b)\ne b$.

Thus, the existence of $x \in G$ such that $x^2 \neq e$ in only used in the abelian case, but as the original answer notes, it is not really needed.

Comment: @llrf If G is not abelian , in your example just take $x \notin Z(G)$.

Comment: This answer is just a distillation of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/8401/589.

Comment: This may be a distillation... But i can understand it :) That's the point :) and i appreciate that :)