# If G is a group and $|Aut(G)|=1$then prove G’=(e)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

This is a question from a textbook:
If G is a group and $|Aut(G)|=1$then prove G’=(e)

I’m completely stuck (for about a whole day ), A proper hint or an answer would be so appreciated.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3953362/autg-id-iff-g-leq-2/

Comment: A nonabelian group has nontrivial inner automorphisms, so if there are no nontrivial automorphisms, the group must be abelian. In fact, having no nontrivial automorphisms implies the group is abelian of exponent $2$, and if you assume the Axiom of Choice, it must have nontrivial automorphisms unless it is cyclic of order $2$ or $1$.

Comment: In particular, $G/Z(G)\cong\operatorname{Inn}(G)=1$, which implies $G$ is abelian, and so $G'=1$.