# Examples of a structure that is not closed under taking ultraproducts?

Tags: model-theory, universal-algebra

I simply need some more examples for a short teaching session and am out of interesting ideas, any input would be much appreciated (diagonalizable algebras and those which are similar to them are already in my list).

Comment: The class of the finite structures is not closed under ultraproducts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class $\mathbb{K}$ of structures (in a fixed language) is **elementary** - that is, satisfies $\mathbb{K}=\{\mathcal{A}: \mathcal{A}\models T\}$ for some first-order theory $T$ - iff it is closed under isomorphisms, ultra*products*, and ultra*roots*. Consequently, non-elementary but isomorphism-closed classes form good candidates for classes not closed under ultraproducts. In practice, in fact, I don't know of any naturally-occurring non-elementary class of structures which is ZFC-provably closed under both isomorphisms and under ultraproducts.

Some examples, which you can verify are indeed not closed under ultraproducts:

- The class of **well-orderings**.
- The class of structures of cardinality $<\kappa$ for any fixed infinite cardinal $\kappa$.
- The class of **torsion groups**, or - for exactly the same reason - the class of **fields of positive characteristic**.
- The class of **rigid** (= no nontrivial automorphisms) **rings**. Here "rigid rings" can be replaced by "rigid Xs" for most, but not all, types of X; for example, [the only rigid *groups* are those with $<3$ elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8379/g2-implies-g-has-non-trivial-automorphism) so the class of rigid groups is boringly elementary.

Comment: I'm curious about your characterisation of elementary classes. Where do the ultraroots come from? I know this if you replace ultraroot by elementary substructure. Do you mean that if $M\preceq N$, then we can find ultrapowers $M^{\mathcal U}\cong N^{\mathcal V}$? (Or maybe even $M^{\mathcal U}\cong N^{\mathcal U}$?) Or is it more complicated?

Comment: @tomasz Yup - this is due to [Keisler-Shelah](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/Keisler-Shelah+isomorphism+theorem) (Keisler proved it assuming $\mathsf{GCH}$ and Shelah got a $\mathsf{ZFC}$-only proof; for nuances of the role of cardinal arithmetic here, see e.g. [Golshani-Shelah](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.03977)).

Comment: Ah, right, I do actually know that one, I guess the "ultraroot" threw me off.